# Kohana 3 arr::rotate

Tags: arrays, kohana, rotation

I am trying to make a multiplet file upload in kohana 3.
i don't know the number of files that will be uploaded. i tried doing this usind arr::roate, but it seems not being a method of kohana 3.

```
foreach( arr::rotate($_FILES['product_image']) as $file )
{    
    $variable = Upload::save($_FILES['product_image'], NULL, APPPATH . 'media' . '/');
    $product_image->image = basename($variable);
}
```

How can I do arr::rotate in ko3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For now, you can copy the method from a kohana2 codebase into an extended arr class. We will likely add it into Kohana 3.2.

Comment: i see. and where exactly can i find the code for this method? thanks!

Comment: There's a link on the download page to the 2.x archives: http://kohanaframework.org/download

Comment: now i keep getting an error: Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in when i make:    foreach ($value as $k => $v)
 in arr:rotate

Comment: You need at least a 2x2 array to use the method. It won't work on X by 1 arrays.

Comment: now i get  is_uploaded_file() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in ... kohana/upload.php :(